# Three.js: ThreeX not capturing mouseover or mouseout of 3d object

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm trying to put mouseover and mouseout events on a 3d obj (Blender scene) in a Three.js environment with the ThreeX helper.

For some reason in my code ThreeX is only catching click, mouseup and mousedown, but not mouseover or mouseout, and is also not acting on my eventListener. What am I doing wrong?

Mouseover the shoe, then click on the shoe to see the click events fire. What should happen on mouseover of the shoe is what is happening on mouseover of the 'expand' button.

[Here's my code demo](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/3/) 
([and the json model file](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/3/models/shoe4.json)).

Here's my js:

```
 var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();  
    loader.load("models/shoe4.json", function (obj) {
        scene.add (obj);
        scene.rotation.y = Math.PI/1;


     solefoam = obj.getObjectByName( "sole-foam", true );
     sole = obj.getObjectByName( "sole", true );


    THREEx.DomEvents.eventNames.forEach(function(eventName){
      if( eventName === 'mousemove' ) return
      domEvents.addEventListener(obj, eventName, function(event){
        var domElement  = document.querySelector('#logs')
        domElement.innerHTML  = event.type + '<br/>' + domElement.innerHTML
      }, false)
    })

    obj.addEventListener('click', function(object3d){ 
      over();
     });

    });   

function over(){
  TweenLite.to(solefoam.position , 1, {y: -2.5, ease:Sine.easeInOut} );
  TweenLite.to(sole.position, 1, {y: -5, ease:Sine.easeInOut} );
}
```

[Here's an example from the threex website of threeX correctly picking up mouseover and mouseout events.](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.domevents/examples/demo.html)